# Where to see item cache or data cache is stored?

Tags: caching, site-configuration, patch-configuration

I have just enabled the below caches in web config file, now how to see the cache is storing in particular location or not ? If so which file or database table i have to check ?

```
<setting name="Caching.Enabled" value="true" /><setting name="Caching.ItemCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
```

and

```
<databases>
  <database id="web">
    <cacheSizes role:require="ContentDelivery or Standalone">
      <data>500MB</data>
      <items>500MB</items>
    </cacheSizes>
  </database>
</databases>
```

Comment: This unofficial documentation page explains pretty well the available Sitecore in-memory caching options: https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20Fundamentals/Caching/

Answer (score 2):

Caching is stored in memory, not in database or files.

You can check the cache sizes from `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`, which will let you check the max size they have been configured and how much they have been filled.

There is nothing out of the box which allows you to inspect the cache and what is being stored in them, but generally speaking for item caches it's more important to look at how much they are being filled, the cache hits and the cache misses. Cache information is also [periodically dumped to disk](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/periodically-saving-information-about-cache-and-rendering-statistics/), which can be useful on Content Delivery environments.

Comment: Thanks @jammykum, your answers is really helpful.